# React-Native Requiring BREAK IN PRODUCTION Warning

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I am requiring a JSON file, which is bundled in react-native and using its react-native generated `verboseNamesToModuleId` i am requiring that file at runtime.

But i am getting the following warning :

> Requiring module 'MyReactNativeApp/test.json' by name is only
>   supported for debugging purposes and will BREAK IN PRODUCTION!

react-native version : *0.41.1*

code  :

```
 require('./test.json') // bundled by react-native
 var verboseName = 'myreactnativeapp/test.json'  // verbosename generated by react-native in require.js
 var obj = require(verboseName) // requiring same file using verbosename
```

How to resolve this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, a solution would be to try to set the test1, test2, test3 jsons files as properties of a Component(lets say `TestService`), import it then access its properties dynamically.

Other solution might be to fetch the data from back end.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: i wan to require test.json dynamically using require within some function.
Thats why i am using react generated verbosename to require.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, Do you mean to require these file in an object and keep it like a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: hey, i defined my images in a separate file and i required it in my component but i keep getting this "requiring module 'projectName/path/image.png' by name is only supported for debugging purposes and will BREAK IN PRODUCTION" .. any idea please

Comment: Please show here some content from the file and how you import it. Have you tried using import instead of require?

Comment: I found these links about the ES6 import and export very useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export